# Access to the path 'C:\WebSite1' is denied while downloading and after uploading file/image file name is showing up in gridview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Access to the path 'C:\WebSite1' is denied while downloading and after uploading file/image file name is showing up in gridview in asp.net

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.cs" Inherits="Default2" %>

  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">

      <div>
        <asp:FileUpload ID="fileUpload1" runat="server" />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="btnUpload" runat="server" Text="Upload" onclick="btnUpload_Click" />
        <%-- <asp:GridView ID="gvDetails" CssClass="Gridview" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="FilePath">
          <HeaderStyle BackColor="#df5015" />
          <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="FileName" HeaderText="FileName" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FilePath">
              <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" runat="server" Text="Download" OnClick="lnkDownload_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
              </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
          </Columns>
          </asp:GridView>--%>


          <asp:GridView ID="gvDetails" runat="server" DataKeyNames="FilePath" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
            <Columns>
              <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="id" />
              <asp:BoundField DataField="FileName" HeaderText="Filename" />
              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FilePath">
                <ItemTemplate>

                  <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" runat="server" Text="download" OnClick="lnkDownload_Click"></asp:LinkButton>

                </ItemTemplate>
              </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
          </asp:GridView>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>

  </html>
```

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.Odbc;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page

{
OdbcConnection conn= new    
OdbcConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["demo1"].ConnectionString);
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
{

bindgridview();

}
}

private void bindgridview()
{
conn.Open();
    OdbcDataAdapter da= new OdbcDataAdapter("select * from test5",conn);
    DataSet ds= new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    gvDetails.DataSource= ds;
    gvDetails.DataBind();



}
//protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
//{
//   // string filename = "download.pdf";
//   // System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
//   // Response.Clear();
//    //Response.ClearContent();
//    Response.ContentType="image/jpg";
//    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition" , "attachement; Filename=hello.pdf       ;" );
//    Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("~/6028656-20160315.pdf"));
//   // Response.Flush();
//   // Response.End();

//    //Response.Write("<script>alert('Hello');</script>");



//}
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string filename = Path.GetFileName(fileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    fileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Files/" + filename));

    conn.Open();
    OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("insert into test5(FileName,FilePath) values(@Name,@Path)", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", filename);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Path", "Files/" + filename);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
    conn.Close();
    bindgridview();

    btnUpload.Attributes.Add("onclick", "document.getElementById('" + fileUpload1.ClientID + "').click();");
}


protected void lnkDownload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lnkbtn = sender as LinkButton;
    GridViewRow gvrow = lnkbtn.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
    string filePath = gvDetails.DataKeys[gvrow.RowIndex].Value.ToString();
    Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=~\"" + filePath + "\"");
    Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(filePath));
    Response.End();}
```

[i am getting this error while downloading the `file/image from the gridview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EBtvf.jpg)

Comment: Because this is a web application you need to incorporate impersonation to access the file system outside of your application. You would call your impersonation in the method btnUpload before you attempt to access the file. Here is the code needed to enable impersonation: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306158

Comment: @Gregg hi greg....i tried your way...but now its giving me some "Configuration Error"....something like this "could not create Windows user token from the credentials specified in the config file. Error from the operating system 'Unspecified error".....any suggestions